# Python: Selenium no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@data-id=1]"}

Tags: python, django, selenium, unit-testing

Why I got this error `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@data-id=1]"}`

test.py

```
zone = Zone.objects.last()
self.browser.refresh()
time.sleep(2)
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-id="+str(zone.id)+"]").click() # zone.id = 1
```

I have also tried with **self.browser.find_element_by_id('update_id_'+str(zone.id))** but not working :( 
what's wrong going on ?
html

```
<button type="button" id="updateButton update_id_2" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary updateButton" data-id="2">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Your html button has id 2 but your xpath is with id 1 ( also this is not https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using zone id ? You can simply use ID to locate your element

Answer (score -1):

From the error message and the code for Button, I could see that `zone.id` value is coming wrong. The value of `zone.id` is coming as 1 instead of 2.

You can try using,

```
self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-xs.btn-primary.updateButton').click()
```

or

```
self.browser.find_element_by_id('updateButton update_id_2').click()
```

If you can give bit more HTML code, I can give you the implementation of above using `find_element_by_xpath`.